# Invalid data table format: column #1 must be of type 'string'. GANTT CHART ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, charts, google-visualization

i am try to use gantt chart in my app with 3 fields Name,Start(date) , End(date) but always i have this error     Invalid data table format: column #1 must be of type 'string'.  and also i am converting the date but without any success my json get date like this '2020 , 09 , 01' and i add new Date(2020 , 09 , 01)
someone have any idea :) thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['gantt'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw_Charts);
            function draw_Charts() {
                var options = {
                    title: 'title',
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Data.asmx/GetChartData",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                        dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Start');
                        dataTable.addColumn('date','End');
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                            var name = response.d[i][0].toString();
                            var start = new Date(response.d[i][1].toString());
                            var end = new Date(response.d[i][2].toString());
                            dataTable.addRows([[name,start, end]]);
                        }
                        
                        //var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('gantt')[0]);
                        var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt($("#gantt")[0]);
                        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
                    },
                    failure: function (r) {
                            alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                        },
                        error: function (r) {
                            alert(r.status + " - " + r.statusText);
                        }
                });
                
            }
```

Comment: `[[name,start, end]]` ... are you sure you need a 2d array? perhaps `[name,start, end]`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes bro

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with that library so, just thought it looked odd to pass a 2D array

Comment: since they are using `addRows`, yes, 2d `[[name,start, end]]` -- could also use `addRow`, which would take 1d `[name,start, end]`